# gradle `it` property inside `build.gradle` closures

Tags: gradle, groovy

Where does that property `it` stored in gradle?

```
subprojects {
    println it.class.name // DefaultProject_Decorated
    dependencies {
        println it.class.name // DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated
```

Because it should not be the default `it` property of the closure. Or it should?

I think it something like `def it = this` or maybe I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In groovy closures, `it` is the default parameter passed to the Closure.

So:

```
def friendly = { "Hello $it" }

assert friendly('tim') == 'Hello tim'
```

So in the above cases, Gradle passes the object that the closure is helping to configure into the closure itself.

Comment: Oh I see. Did not know about that. I thought you either params or not. Is it documented somewhere? Guess I missed it,